# Laravel 4 - Insert through hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my model relationship...

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function loginLog(){
        return $this->hasMany('LoginLog');
    }
}

class LoginLog extends Eloquent {
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

When I insert data into the `login_logs` table in my database all the data is input correctly but it does not insert the id of the user into **user_id** (laravel expects this).

Here is how I am inserting into `login_logs`.

```
$user->loginLog()->insert(array(
    'user_id'       => $user->id, //I could put it here, but then what is the point in a relationship?
    'email'         => $user->email,
    'ip_address'    => Request::getClientIp(),
    'country_code'  => $country_code,
    'status'        => $status,
    'created_at'    => Helper::dateTimeNow()
));
```

Comment: Because you didn't put insert user_id column values into `loginLog()` insert query? Quite confused though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach the user.

Its here in the docs
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models

Update:

On rereading your question I think you want to find the user by their id first as you are doing `$user->loginLog()->insert` not `$loginLog->insert`

Try chaining it so:
`$user::find($theIDYouWant)->loginLog()->insert`

Comment: $user was already set to the found user. However, your post pointed me in the correct position and now it's working, thanks.